# Bash: Capture / Use last (or Nth) line in stdout

Tags: bash, command-line

## Query

I use Bash. When I'm looking for files, often I'll do the following:

`find -name stackexchange.hs`

And often the results will look like:

```
/youre/the/man/now/dog/stackexchange.hs
/you/are/no/longer/the/dog/dog/stackexchange.hs
/this/is/the/file/i/want/stackexchange.hs
```

Then I'll want to do one of the following:

- Option 1: Open the last item in the list of results in **vim**.
- Option 2: Open the Nth item in the list of results in **vim**.

Currently, I cut-and-paste with the mouse. Which brings me to my **question**:

1. Is there an easy, one-liner to accomplish options 1&2? Note that this is occurring *after* the `find` command.
2. Is there a way to capture N-lines from stdout in some kind of bash vector/array?

### Ideal usage

```
$ find -name am_i_really_all_alone.txt
./borges/library/you_are_not_alone.txt
./borges/library/am_i_really_all_alone.txt
$ vim (N)
```

(syntax and semantics may differ, but you get the point)

## Similaria

There seem to be several similar questions. Here are my *perceived* differences (I am open to enlightenment):

- ["Open File Found with find Command"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/open-file-found-with-find-command) focuses on creating a one-line to pipe a file name from `find` into `vim` (or whatever). In my case, I want to `find` first, pipe later (so to speak). My capture / usage happens strictly *after*.
- ["Reuse Last Output From Command Lind"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-do-i-reuse-the-last-output-from-the-command-line) seems bang-on, but seems to simply repeat the command and doesn't speak to capturing the **Nth** line of output. Quite frankly, it scares me.
- ["Capture Multi-Line Output of a Bash Builtin"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/capture-multi-line-output-of-a-bash-builtin) is close, but not quite there.
- ["What is the exact difference between terminal, shell, tty, console, etc."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-do-i-reuse-the-last-output-from-the-command-line) this one is really just a good read.

Thank you for your help! Having used *nix/BSD when I was a teenager in the 90s and getting scared away by calling my burnout, acid-head neighbour to help me install drivers for my plug-and-play sound card, I'm relieved to discuss command-line minutiae with (perceivably) less frightening individuals. It feels good to be back.

Comment: I think, that if you know it before that you want to open the last result, you could use something like `vim $(command |tail -n1)`.

Comment: I posted a similar question here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348224/quick-way-to-open-results-from-find-or-locate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a potential solution to your issue that should be *reasonably* (but not perfectly) safe in the presence of funky file names (doesn't handle filenames with linefeeds in them - probably fixable, but there might be other problems lurking).

Two functions, the first one runs `find` with the parameters you pass it, saves the output in an array, and displays them. The second is just a helper to access that array.

```
myfind() {
  IFS=$'\n' __last_find_result=($(find "$@"));
  printf "%s\n" "${__last_find_result[@]}";
}
myget() {
  echo "${__last_find_result[$1]}";
}
```

Use case:

```
$ myfind . -name "c*"
./a b/c d
./.git/config
./.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
$ vim "$(myget 0)"
# This opens the "./a b/c d" file.
$ vim "$(myget 2)"
# This opens ".git/hooks/commit-msg.sample"
```

Quotes not required around the `$(myget index)` if you don't have whitespace or other troublesome characters in your filenames.
Pushes the whole output of `find` to your environment, which might be limited. (Using a temporary file rather than that array would solve that, but has other issues - notably concurrent use from multiple shells.)

Comment: I can't upvote you because I don't have enough of a reputation, so here is a, uh, verbal one:

"upvote"

Answer (score 6):

I've got this in my `.screenrc`:

```
bind -c pasteline 1 eval copy 'stuff "-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 2 eval copy 'stuff "2-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 3 eval copy 'stuff "3-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 4 eval copy 'stuff "4-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 5 eval copy 'stuff "5-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 6 eval copy 'stuff "6-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 7 eval copy 'stuff "7-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 8 eval copy 'stuff "8-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 9 eval copy 'stuff "9-Y"' 'paste .'
bindkey ¬ command -c pasteline
```

Basically, in screen, <kbd>¬</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, pastes the line above the cursor, <kbd>¬</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, pastes the second line above the cursor... and so on. You may want to add more for lines 10 and above, but I find that after about 7 already, I'd rather use the mouse or `screen`'s copy mode than counting the number of lines to get the one I want.

Answer (score 0):

another solution is: you can write an interactive script that will automatically ask for your choice.
here is the code for interactive script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter your choice : z for last argument or a number for that file"
read choice

case "$choice" in
z) eval vim \$$#;;
*)eval  vim \$$choice;;
esac
```

save this script with any name say "autofind"
and invoke the script with your "find command" as argument
here is the code to invoke script:

```
./autofind `your find command`
```

But before using the script check your "find command" whether it is giving result or not.If it is showing some result then only use the script

Answer (score 0):

Mats answer was just what I was looking for. I've expanded his code a bit to allow for more get-options.

```
$ f ~/scripts -name '*.sh'
$ vim $(g foo)  # edit all find results matching "foo"
$ vim $(g 1 3 5) # edit find results number 1, 3 and 5
$ vim $(g 3-5) # edit find results 3-5
$ vim $(g 5-) # edit find results 5 to last
$ vim $(g -7) # edit find result 7 from bottom
$ vim $(g 1 4-5 -7 9- foo) # all of the above combined
```

.

```
f() {
    IFS=$'\n' __last_find_result=($(find "$@"));
    printf "%s\n" "${__last_find_result[@]}";
}

g() {
    len=${#__last_find_result[@]}
    pad=${#len}
    numbers=""
    if [ "$1" == "-n" ]; then
        numbers=1
        shift
    fi
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        if [ -n "$numbers" ]; then
            n=1;
            for e in "${__last_find_result[@]}";do
                printf "%0${pad}d. %s\n" "$n" "$e"
                let n=n+1
            done
        else
            printf "%s\n" "${__last_find_result[@]}"
        fi
    else
        for l in $@;do
            if [[ "$l" =~ ([^0-9-]+) ]];then
                n=1;
                for e in "${__last_find_result[@]}";do
                    if [[ $e =~ $1 ]]; then
                        if [ -n "$numbers" ];then
                            printf "%0${pad}d. %s\n" "$n" "$e"
                        else
                            printf "%s\n" "$e"
                        fi
                    fi
                    let n=n+1
                done
            elif [[ "$l" =~ ^([0-9]+)$ ]];then
                let l=l-1
                echo "${__last_find_result[$l]}";
            elif [[ "$l" =~ ^([0-9]*)(-)?([0-9]*)$ ]]; then
                from=${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
                dash=${BASH_REMATCH[2]};
                to=${BASH_REMATCH[3]};
                if [ -z "$from" ]; then # -n
                    [ $to -gt ${#__last_find_result[@]} ] && to=${#__last_find_result[@]}
                    echo "${__last_find_result[-$to]}";
                else # n-m
                    [ -z "$to" ] && to=${#__last_find_result[@]}
                    [ $to -gt ${#__last_find_result[@]} ] && to=${#__last_find_result[@]}
                    let to=$to-1
                    let from=$from-1
                    n=$(($from+1))
                    for i in `seq $from $to`;do
                        if [ -n "$numbers" ];then
                            printf "%0${pad}d. %s\n" "$n" "${__last_find_result[$i]}"
                        else
                            printf "%s\n" "${__last_find_result[$i]}"
                        fi
                        let n=n+1
                    done
                fi
            fi
        done
    fi
}
```